# Error installing dnsmasq on ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, dnsmasq

When I try to install dnsmasq on ubuntu server 14.04.2 it fails, but on ubuntu desktop it works fine.

I'm trying to install it using `apt-get install dnsmasq`
I have update and upgrade the system.

The error it throws is the next:

`Ikerlan @ server1: ~ $ sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
They could not install some packages. This may mean that
He requested an impossible situation or if you are using the distribution
unstable, that some required packages have not been created or have
They have been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  dnsmasq: Depends: init-system-helpers (> = 1.18 ~) but 1.14 will be installed
E: We were unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
sudo wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/trusty.de-md.libre | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9

sudo apt-get update
```

It works fine for me